# Should I use the wakelock?

Tags: android, android-service, android-location

I have an Android service, that receives GPS notifications and does some calculations then.

Should I use wakelock in this situation? (like in the following code?)

Can the processor 'fall asleep' in the middle of my calculation?

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) 
{
    mWakeLock.acquire();
    // My calculations here
    mWakeLock.release();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it can't happen because Android gets a wakelock for you until the call ends. Of course, if you do some async work (start another thread and something similar) in your `onLocationChange` you have to take a wakelock.